# how to remove a value from all elements in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have a numpy array created from an image:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('some_image.png')
pixels = np.array(img)
pixels.shape
(900, 1800, 4)
```

so that's 900 pixels high, 1800 pixels wide, and 4 channels (RGBA) per pixel.  Each pixel element looks something like `[220 193 254 255]` for Red, Green, Blue and Alpha.

I'd like to remove that final `255` from each element, as it represents 'alpha' (transparency) and is not needed for my purposes.

Comment: `pixels = pixels[:,:,:3]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as pointed out in comments by c2huc2hu :

```
pixels = pixels[:,:,:3]
```